# cy.click() failed because it requires a DOM element. The subject received was: > undefined

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have made a custom command for logout which I am calling in my afterEach hook but every time I am getting this error. Below is the code attached:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
//cy.get('#react-burger-menu-btn').should('be.visible').click({force:true})
cy.xpath("//div[@class = 'bm-burger-button']").click({ force: true })
cy.get('#react-burger-menu-btn')
cy.get('#logout_sidebar_link').click()})
```

I am using the Swag Labs dummy website. Attaching the website's link as well for reference:
https://www.saucedemo.com/

Took help from the documentation but unable to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can try waiting for visibility of all the elements involved.

```js
cy.get('#react-burger-menu-btn').should('be.visible')
cy.get('#logout_sidebar_link').should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

If it does not work, look at the HTML of the menu and try checking other elements for visibility as well.

You should open the devtools and observe which elements are modified after the click (they will flash in the devtools Elements tab).

Comment: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

  > visible

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

  > undefined

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.

Because this error occurred during a after each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: Hooks

Comment: Getting this as an error now.

Comment: You are obviously not following my code -  that message would not be possible if you used it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
    cy.get('button[id="react-burger-menu-btn"]').click()
    cy.get('#logout_sidebar_link').click()
});
```

Try this

Comment: Getting the same error again. Used force: true as well but still getting the error.